# Is it possible to put a line break into a 'mailto:' rewrite in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mailto

For complex reasons I've had to remove an enquiry form from a web site and use a 'mailto:' instead. For simplicity I've changed the htaccess file so that the former 'contact' link to the form now becomes a 'mailto:' as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^contact$ mailto:myname@mydomain.com?subject=BusinessName\ BandB\ Enquiry&body=You\ can\ find\ our\ availability\ on\ line.\ Delete\ this\ content\ if\ inapplicable
```

That does work, my local e-mail client (Thunderbird) opens with the information correctly shown in subject and body. (My TB is set to compose in plain text, I've yet to test with HTML)

I would like to introduce a new line in the body so that 'Delete this content if inapplicable' is on a separate line. Is there any way to do this? Given mod_rewrite's intended purpose I could understand if there isn't but I thought I'd ask before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to introduce a *new line* in the body so that 'Delete this content if inapplicable' is on a separate line.

New lines in the body need are represented by two characters: carriage return (char 13) + line feed (char 10) (see [RFC2368](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt)). This would need to be URL encoded in the resulting URL as `%0D%0A`.

When used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string the literal `%` characters would need to backslash-escaped to negate their special meaning as a backreference to the preceding *CondPattern* (which there isn't one). ie. `\%0D\%0A`. Otherwise, you will end up with the string `DA`, because there is no `%0` backreference in this example.

You can also avoid having to backslash-escape all the literal spaces by encloses the entire argument (*substitution* string) in double quotes.

So, try the following instead:

`RewriteRule ^contact$ "mailto:myname@mydomain.com?subject=BusinessName BandB Enquiry&body=You can find our availability on line.\%0D\%0ADelete this content if inapplicable" [R,L]`

Comment: I had tried somethnig like that to escape the urlencoded %20 spaces normally used in a mailto, but it always showed the zeros in my e-mail client, so I fell back on 'slash-space'. I'll give it another go.

Comment: No joy. The '\%0D\%0A' just prints as is in the e-mail body. '\\%0D\\%0A' just prints the D and the A (and the other text). But never a newline. I suspect it's not possible.